# Group by and sum query on multiple columns

Tags: c#, linq

```
var fpslist = db.FPSinformations.Where(x => x.Godown_Code != null && x.Godown_Code == godownid).ToList();
var data1 = fpslist.GroupBy(x => x.Ration_Card_Type1)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        CardType_Name = x.Key,
        CardType_Count = x.Sum(y => y.Ration_Card_Count1)
    }).ToList();
var data2 = fpslist.GroupBy(x => x.Ration_Card_Type2)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        CardType_Name = x.Key,
        CardType_Count = x.Sum(y => y.Ration_Card_Count2)
    }).ToList();
var data3 = fpslist.GroupBy(x => x.Ration_Card_Type3)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        CardType_Name = x.Key,
        CardType_Count = x.Sum(y => y.Ration_Card_Count3)
    }).ToList();
var data4 = fpslist.GroupBy(x => x.Ration_Card_Type4)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        CardType_Name = x.Key,
        CardType_Count = x.Sum(y => y.Ration_Card_Count4)
    }).ToList();
var data5 = fpslist.GroupBy(x => x.Ration_Card_Type5)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        CardType_Name = x.Key,
        CardType_Count = x.Sum(y => y.Ration_Card_Count5)
    }).ToList();

var GodownRCCount = data1.Where(x => x.CardType_Name != null).ToList();
var GodownRCCounts = GodownRCCount;
GodownRCCount = data2.Where(x => x.CardType_Name != null).ToList();
GodownRCCounts.AddRange(GodownRCCount);
GodownRCCount = data3.Where(x => x.CardType_Name != null).ToList();
GodownRCCounts.AddRange(GodownRCCount);
GodownRCCount = data4.Where(x => x.CardType_Name != null).ToList();
GodownRCCounts.AddRange(GodownRCCount);
GodownRCCount = data5.Where(x => x.CardType_Name != null).ToList();
GodownRCCounts.AddRange(GodownRCCount);
```

I have 10 columns in my database like this:

> ```
> Ration_Card_Type1
> Ration_card_count1
> Ration_Card_Type2
> Ration_card_count2
> Ration_Card_Type3
> Ration_card_count3
> Ration_Card_Type4
> Ration_card_count4
> Ration_Card_Type5
> Ration_card_count5
> ```

Now what I want is to get the sum of `Ration_Card_Counts` and its type from its type.

**Expected output:**

> ```
> CardType_Name
> CardType_Count
> ```

It works fine, but I want to optimize it in max possible way as this will be inside a loop.

Comment: Do you have any power to get the database changed? You're jumping through hoops because it's not been properly normalized.

Comment: yes I have what will be your suggestion?

Comment: You're "asking for advice about code not yet written", and [such questions are off-topic](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @BCdotWEB no i have already implemented the code above but wanted it to improve as well as was open to any db changes etc

Answer (score 3):

First and most obvious issue is usage of `ToList()`, it's not required and you force creation of multiple (and possibly big) lists moreover you're repeating almost same code again and again. Step by step:

```
var fpslist = db.FPSinformations.Where(x => x.Godown_Code == godownid);
```

Unless comparison operator for `Godown_Code` is broken then you shouldn't need to check for null (in case you may opt for `?.` to avoid it). Also you don't need `.ToList()`, drop it. If you will execute such code inside a loop you may consider to move this outside the loop (to be sure more context is needed).

Now let's make a reusable function (and also avoid to create multiple anonymous types, it's a micro optimization but it also simplifies our code):

```
static IEnumerable<Tuple<TName, TCount>> CountByType<T, TName, TCount>(
    IEnumerable<T> list,
    Func<T, TName> nameSelector,
    Func<IEnumerable<T>, TCount> aggregator)
{
    return list.Where(x => Object.Equals(nameSelector(x), null) == false)
        .GroupBy(x => nameSelector(x))
        .Select(x => Tuple.Create(x.Key, aggregator(x)));
}
```

Now your code can be greatly simplified (I assumed you cannot change database columns otherwise everything can be even simpler, see last section of this answer). I also used generics because type of your columns is unknown.

```
    var data1 = CountByType(fpslist, 
        x => x.Ration_Card_Type1,
        x => x.Sum(y => y.Ration_Card_Count1));

    var data2 = CountByType(fpslist, 
        x => x.Ration_Card_Type2,
        x => x.Sum(y => y.Ration_Card_Count2));

   // Repeat for each set

   var result = data1
       .Concatenate(data2)
       .Concatenate(data3)
       .Concatenate(data4)
       .Concatenate(data5);
```

Note that from your code it seems you can have multiple rows with a value for `Ration_Card_CountX`. If you have just one row then all code will be greatly reduced. Here I used a `Tuple<T1, T2>` because I do not know exact types of your objects, you'd better use a proper class instead.

Note that you can consume `result` as-is (an enumeration) or materialize a list (don't forget this if data comes from DB and connection will be disposed, LINQ execution is deferred).

---

**About DB**

I do not know if you can change your database schema and I do not know exact layout of your data then this section may not apply in your case.

If your data is in the form:

```
Ration_Card_Type1   Ration_Card_Count1   Ration_Card_Type2   Ration_Card_Count2
Type1                                5   NULL                                 0
NULL                                 0   Type2                               11
Type1                               12   Type2                                3
```

Then you have to keep your actual code but I would suggest to do not map 1:1 column names with C# property names (conventions are pretty different) then `Ration_Card_Type1` should be `RationCardType1` (assuming you can't simply have `Type1`, `Type2` and so on).

If, for example, you have data with this simplified layout:

```
Ration_Card_Type1   Ration_Card_Count1   Ration_Card_Type2   Ration_Card_Count2
Type1                                5   NULL                                 0
NULL                                 0   Type2                               11
Type1                               12   NULL                                 0
```

Then you may both optimize and simplify your DB (it will also impact code):

```
Type   Count
1          5
2         11
1         12
```

In that case all you need (assuming your C# entities maps 1:1 with DB columns):

```
var result = db.GroupBy(x => x.Type)
    .Select(x => new { Type = x.Key, Count = x.Sum(y => y.Count) });
```

Comment: I'm open to database changes as well

Comment: On the same db row can you have a value for each tuple name & count?

Comment: how are you saying can you show me an example?

Comment: Ok, few hours to be in office! Breakfast time here :-)

Comment: ok enjoy :) it's almost 12 noon here :)

Comment: hi there? need a clarification

Comment: yes, tell me! About what?

Comment: can you check the other answer , have question on that

Comment: Which question? If it's directly about the other answer I think Topin is better one to answer it!

Comment: yes but i think he is not available just need to know what actually should be comming in the '??' place

Comment: LOL actual types of your properties. We don't see your full code then we can just guess types (string, int, int?). That's why I used generics in my answer (even if they complicate syntax) and he put ?? as placeholder you have to replace with real types.

Comment: I tried to pass the model which will be as queryable to but then in that case getting this error "does not contain a definition for 'GroupBy' and the best extension method overload 'ParallelEnumerable.GroupBy<string, in>(Parallel Query<string>, Func<string, int>)' requires a receiver of type 'Parallel Query<string>"

Comment: Hard to say without _visible_ code! Wrong types?

Comment: i have put all the relevant code in the question
`db.FPSinformations.Where(x => x.Godown_Code == godownid);`

Comment: No, for example what's the type of Godown_Code? string? int? Nullable<int>? object? decimal? Guid?

Comment: Godown_Code is nullable string

Answer (score 3):

From what you gave us, there's nothing you can do to optimize your query except changing the way your data is stored.

Having `Ration_Card_Count[1..5]` is a big code smell. There's something wrong in the implementation.

Though, you could change this code to be a little less repetitive.

Most code is duplicated in there, so let's refactor it :

```
var data1 = fpslist.GroupBy(x => x.Ration_Card_Type1)
.Select(x => new
{
    CardType_Name = x.Key,
    CardType_Count = x.Sum(y => y.Ration_Card_Count1)
}).ToList();
```

This could be extracted in a method but beforehand, we need to create a small data type for your anonymous type because methods cannot return anonymous types.

```
struct CardGrouping
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}

private static IEnumerable<CardGrouping> GetCardGrouping(IQueryable<??> queryable, Func<???, int> groupingFunction)
{
    return queryable.GroupBy(groupingFunction)
        .Select(x => new CardGrouping()
        {
            Name = x.Key,
            Count = x.Sum(groupingFunction)
        }).ToList();
}
```

Notice the `???`, they're here because there's not enough context in your question, I can't figure what type to use. In your next question, please add more context! :)

Now, we've got a method that does the nasty work for us, let's see what the code looks like :

```
var data1 = GetCardGrouping(fpsList, y => y.Ration_Card_Count1);
var data2 = GetCardGrouping(fpsList, y => y.Ration_Card_Count2);
var data3 = GetCardGrouping(fpsList, y => y.Ration_Card_Count3);
var data4 = GetCardGrouping(fpsList, y => y.Ration_Card_Count4);
var data5 = GetCardGrouping(fpsList, y => y.Ration_Card_Count5);

var GodownRCCount = data1.Where(x => x.CardType_Name != null).ToList();
var GodownRCCounts = GodownRCCount;
GodownRCCount = data2.Where(x => x.CardType_Name != null).ToList();
GodownRCCounts.AddRange(GodownRCCount);
GodownRCCount = data3.Where(x => x.CardType_Name != null).ToList();
GodownRCCounts.AddRange(GodownRCCount);
GodownRCCount = data4.Where(x => x.CardType_Name != null).ToList();
GodownRCCounts.AddRange(GodownRCCount);
GodownRCCount = data5.Where(x => x.CardType_Name != null).ToList();
GodownRCCounts.AddRange(GodownRCCount);
```

You repeat `x => x.CardType_Name != null` with every `data`, so maybe we should add this to our method :

```
private static IEnumerable<CardGrouping> GetCardGrouping(IQueryable<??> queryable, Func<??, int> groupingFunction)
{
    return queryable.GroupBy(groupingFunction)
            .Where(x => x.Key != null)
            .Select(x => new CardGrouping
            {
                Name = x.Key,
                Count = x.Sum(groupingFunction)
            }).ToList();
}
```

Now what does it look like :

```
var data1 = GetCardGrouping(fpsList, y => y.Ration_Card_Count1);
var data2 = GetCardGrouping(fpsList, y => y.Ration_Card_Count2);
var data3 = GetCardGrouping(fpsList, y => y.Ration_Card_Count3);
var data4 = GetCardGrouping(fpsList, y => y.Ration_Card_Count4);
var data5 = GetCardGrouping(fpsList, y => y.Ration_Card_Count5);

var GodownRCCounts = new List<???>();
GodownRCCounts.AddRange(data1);
GodownRCCounts.AddRange(data2);
GodownRCCounts.AddRange(data3);
GodownRCCounts.AddRange(data4);
GodownRCCounts.AddRange(data5);
```

The naming is pretty terrible. Snake_Case shouldn't be used in C#. If you can change all those `Ration_Card_Count5` to `RationCardCount5`, it'd be great. Also, variable shouldn't be PascalCased, but camelCased. So `GodownRCCounts = godownRCCounts`.

Lastly, try to use `var` only when it's possible to guess the type used by reading the code. Right now it is impossible and it makes the code harder to read/review.

**Edit** : I don't think this code even works. Is `Ration_Card_Count` an `int` or a `string`? Or maybe a `Nullable<int>`? Because you use it in the `Sum` function, which takes an `int`, but you also check for `null`, which isn't a possible value for `int`. What does that mean?? If you check `int == null`, you can remove **all** the checks for that, it'll never happen.

Comment: Ration_Card_Count is an int
CardType_Name is being checked for Null and is a string
What additional information do you need, sorry for not being descriptive my 1st time in codereview
thanks for the small updates, most of the code is not mine, but i will surely try to change it

Comment: You shouldn't check the `int` for `null`, because that can never happen! :) And It's alright, first time is hard for everyone. In your next question, try to put as much context as possible! :)

Comment: im checking the name for null not the int

Comment: Yes but `CardType_Name = x.Key` and `x.Key = y.Ration_Card_Count1`. Unless there's something we're missing in here

Comment: no you are not missing anything but i dont in some cases of groupby null value was getting added in normal scnario the count should be 1 in every case but in few cases count was 2 n 2nd was null so added null case

Comment: There's probably another problem in your code. You shouldn't hide it with the `null` check! :)

Comment: ok :)
Can you suggest any improvement in db as well?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33006/discussion-between-topinfrassi-and-arijit-mukherjee).

Comment: hi there? need a clarification